# sqlite3 - humongous dependency list?

Tags: apt, software-installation, sqlite3

`$ sudo apt-get install sqliteman* sqlite3*`

gives me a display that includes this:

```
...
Recommended packages:
  bacula-sd-mysql bacula-sd-tools cl-sql-backend ada-reference-manual
  gdb-minimal php-http-oauth
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ada-reference-manual-2005 akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-backend-sqlite
  akonadi-server aolserver4-core aolserver4-daemon aolserver4-doc
  aolserver4-nssqlite3 apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data autoconf automake
...
  texlive-xetex tidy tinymce tipa tk8.5 tntdb-sqlite4 tree tzdata-java ulogd
  ulogd-sqlite3 ulogd2 ulogd2-sqlite3 uwsgi-core uwsgi-plugin-sqlite3 vim
  vim-addon-manager vim-runtime wx-common wx2.8-headers wxsqlite3-2.8-dbg
  wxsqlite3-doc zabbix-proxy-sqlite3 zend-framework zend-framework-bin
...
0 upgraded, 797 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1 329 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3 926 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Checking the list I see among others 'TeX, ruby, r-cran, php. openjdk, ocaml, mysql, mono, lua, libreoffice, libjs, libghc, latex, gnustep, gcc-4.6, autotools, bacula. apache2, aolserver, ...'

This list seems so overly long and content-rich that I said No for that install.

Anyone with insight here?

All I want is to get "up and running" on sqlite3 (and nothing else).

I'm a bit of a beginner on SQL,
but see the usefulness both in private projects and at work.
  

**In the end, the basic question:**
Is there some way to reduce that list to a more reasonable one?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use the '*' character on the ends of the packages that you are trying to install?

Comment: As you can see in a comment on @asish 's answer, I expected it to add three more packages. Need to check up what this actually does. Unless you have a hint? ;-)

Comment: The '*' is a wildcard character - look for everything beginning with sqlite3...

Comment: Yes? That was what I expected too! `grep ^sqlite3 TheList | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -re 's/ /, /g'` -> `sqlite3, sqlite3-doc, sqlite3-pcre,` and `sqliteman, sqliteman-doc,` for the second package selection -- out of my saved list.

Comment: `$ ls -l sql*` -> `ls: cannot access sql*: No such file or directory` -- no bash globbing adding stuff either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "*" is the problem here. It selects too many unwanted packages and their dependencies.

Issue a command only as below:

```
sudo apt-get install sqliteman sqlite3
```

Comment: Hmm... That was news for me, I expected these to just add the `*-doc` packages. `sudo apt-get install sqliteman sqliteman-doc  sqlite3 sqlite3-doc sqlite3-pcre` -> Need to get 4 689 kB of archives.\n After this operation, 15,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.\n **Thanks**